# Using switch statements to access functions OOP C++

Tags: c++, oop, switch-statement

I've been trying to use switch statements to access different functions in my program and when I compile the code it keeps showing up the default option, regardless of what I input. Am I missing something really obvious here?

All the functions (all voids) are declared in the class. Is this maybe because I am implementing the other 'menu' functions underneath this one?

```
void bookshop::menu_searchtype() {

std::cout << "Welcome to Hal's Book Emporium!\n\n";

std::cout << "You can search for a book by its:\n";

std::cout << "1. Identification number\n";
std::cout << "2. Title\n";
std::cout << "3. Author\n\n";

std::cout << "Which would you like to use?\n\n";

std::cin >> choice_menu;

int menu_searchtype_no;

switch (menu_searchtype_no) {

    case '1':
        menu_id();
        break;

    case '2':
        menu_title();
        break;

    case '3':
        menu_author();
        break;

    default:
        std::cout << "We seemed to have run into a problem. Please try again\n\n";
        break;
}
```

}

Comment: What's the type of choice_menu? Where is menu_searchtype_no being set? Currently menu_searchtype_no is not initialized so it will always pick the default case for the switch.

Comment: @the_drow: That's not quite true.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Why not?

Comment: int menu_searchtype_no; so use 1 insted of string '1'.

Comment: @the_drow: Why would it "always pick the default case for the switch"? You make it sound like an uninitialised variable has no value, but that's not true: it has an _unspecified value_ and that could easily be 49, 50 or 51. It's just not very likely given the range of an `int` ;)

Comment: @sandipon: `'1'` is not a string.

Comment: sorry @ Lightness Races in Orbit . '1' is char.

Answer (score 3):

- You are reading values into choice_menu and not menu_searchtype_no which you didnt even initialized.
- Your case statement looks like you are comparing for characters. Remove quotes (if you are reading integers and choice_menu is of integer type) and that should let you move further.

Answer (score 1):

You never set `menu_searchtype_no`, so it has an unspecified value. On very rare occasions this may "equal" `'1'`, `'2'` or `'3'` (which is `49`, `50` or `51` respectively, if you're using ASCII), but far more likely it'll be some random-looking higher value which will trigger the `default` case.

I guess you meant to write:

```
switch (choice_menu) {
```

and

```
case 1:
```

etc.